# HTML image preview of a mp4 file

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I build a file browser using phonegap.

Is there a way to show a preview-image or a thumbnail of a mp4 file?

The thumbnail for pictures is just this:

```
<div class="imgListThumb">
     <img class="imgListThumb" src=<%=fullpath%>>
</div>

.imgListThumb 
{
   max-width: 80px;
   max-height: 60px;
}
```

I just want to display a thumbnail in my filebrowser, not a possibility for playback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to generate the thumbnails when you are converting/processing the video to the server. You cannot get an image from the mp4.